# Is "I be quiet" correct?

Tags: imperative-sentences

> I be quiet.

Is it incorrect?

One of my friends told me that ***"I be quiet"*** is an incorrect sentence. I don't know what to say.

Please clear this confusion.

Also, when I looked for this sentence, there was a sentence like.

> You be quiet.

If this is correct, then why is "I be quiet" incorrect? May I know please?

Comment: "I **am** quiet" is correct, if you want to say that you are quiet. Google for [the forms of **to be**](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/to_be.htm)

Comment: It means my friend was right.

Comment: But then *"How can **I be** a good engineer"* seems correct! @CopperKettle

Comment: @CopperKettle - The other grammatical way to say it would be: "I **am being** quiet"

Comment: @MaulikV - It's because you put that "How can" in front. _I be a good engineer_, is incorrect, but _I **am** an engineer_ is perfectly fine. Similarly, "How can I be quiet?" would be just fine, too.

Comment: Strange! If I instruct my daughter - "Hey, *be quiet* for some time, let me concentrate on this" -sounds all okay! @J.R. Furthermore, if kids are playing some games and each kid is playing some professional, some kid may say - no, ***let I be an engineer***, I'm not interested in becoming a doctor. It's not correct even in an informal way?

Comment: *You be quiet* is an imperative.  *\*Let I be an engineer* is simply ungrammatical.

Comment: *Let me be an engineer?* @snailboat

Comment: Sure, *Let me be an engineer* is fine.

Comment: Yeah, I got it now. In imperative sentences "you" is understood.

Comment: It is not correct in standard English. It might be correct in some other dialect. Also *I be quiet* could be used to mimic or represent a speaker of nonstandard English or to provide a humorous effect.

Comment: It has to do with the verbal tense and the conjugation.  Someone above raises the "How can I be...?" question.  The issue is that this is a different verb tense.  "How can I be...?" is in the subjunctive.  "I am..." is in the present indicative.  "To be" is conjugated as "am" in the present indicative.

Comment: Just a note on this -- it strikes me that "I be quiet" may sound correct if you've heard someone say "I'll be quiet", a contraction of I will be quiet. The L sound can be subtle but that makes it correct. It would be an appropriate response. If someone said "You be quiet", which is a command, then the response is "I will be quiet" or "I'll be quiet". There is an implied Yes in this structure, as in Yes, I will be quiet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I be quiet.

You can say "I am/was quiet," but you cannot say "I be quiet". However, you can use this clause in the subjunctive mood as follows:

> They suggest that I be quiet.
>
> Is it essential that I be quiet?

In addition, you can also say "I'd better be quiet".

Comment: @user124234 - Accepted already? [Have you ever read this?](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer)

Answer (score 2):

Also consider this ... "I **'d** be quiet". Note the **'d**. The apostrophe implies a missing letter / letters in this case and implies "I would" be quiet.

Comment: That corrects the sentence,  but doesn't explain why it's incorrect to say "I be".

Comment: @ColleenV This answer provides supplemental information, which answers sometimes do. Also I don't see how the answer by Ale answers the actual question asked.

Answer (score 1):

This is often used with the adverb *better*:

> — *I better **be** quiet.*

It invokes the *subjunctive mood*.

Often, constructions like *it's necessary/important/vital,* etc + *that* + *subject* + base form invoke it.

> — *It's vital that I **be** quiet from now on.*
>   — *It's vital **for me to be** quiet from now on.*

The latter means the same as the former but the infinitive and object pronoun are used.